# list of import statements in python

Tags: python, switch-statement, python-import

I am wanting to call different imports based on the value of a variable in python.

Normally I may do this with a switch statement, but alas python has none...

I was thinking about having a list of functions each of which contains a different import, but is there a better way? Is it possible to list imports in a similar way to methods? Or store the module names as strings in a list, then convert them into a form that can be used to import them?

Thanks

Comment: Python equivalent to a switch statement: `if...elif...elif...else`. Alternative: `optionsDict = {conditionA: funcA, conditionB: funcB, ...}; optionsDict[someCondition]()`

Comment: Why do you have a need to do conditional imports?  Do your modules have lots of side-effects from top-level code?  Do you have lots of modules with name conflicts?  There's a good chance you are trying to cure the symptom rather than the disease here.

Comment: Also, consider using something that makes your intent clear, like [`stevedore`](http://stevedore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). (My hunch is you want its "drivers", but you haven't described your usecase. This is an issue since it means your question might have the XY problem.)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: its for a games loader that loads a game into the same GUI, can quit that game and load another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to import a module programatically, you can do

```
module = __import__('module_name')
```

It seems like a strange situation to find yourself in though.. check your design and proceed with care.

Comment: This, combined with a list or dictionary that maps the key value to the module name, is probably the most concise way to do it.  But I would second @wim's comment that you should probably think twice about how your code is laid out if you are finding yourself needing to use conditional imports.

Comment: future readers:  @Charles Brunet answer should really be the accepted answer.  `importlib` is a better choice than my kludge.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, in Python, you can replace a `switch` structure by a dictionary. To import a module using a name stored into a string, you can use `importlib.import_module()`. Here is an example:

```
from importlib import import_module

modlist = {'case 1': ('package1', 'module1'), 'case 2': ('package2', 'module2')}

myvar = 'case 2'

mypackage, mymodule = modlist[myvar]
import_module(mymodule, mypackage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `if`?

```
if a is "import_module1":
    import module1
elif a is "import_module2":
    import module2
```

Answer (score 0):

An example from my own code http://felicitous-desktop.googlecode.com/files/felicitous.py

The script sets a desktop background. Depending whether the desktop is Windows or Gnome, it imports different libraries:

```
if ( platform.system() == "Windows" ):
    set_windows_background(dest)
else:
    set_gnome_background(dest)
```

where

```
def set_gnome_background(x):
    import gconf
    client = gconf.client_get_default()
    client.set_string ("/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename",x)              

def set_windows_background(x):
  import ctypes
  SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 # According to http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=97142
  import tempfile
  from PIL import Image
  image = Image.open(x)

  bmppath= os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/epic.bmp"))
  image.save (bmppath, "BMP")
  print bmppath
  ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, bmppath , 0)
```